# Flow Chart in Espocrm

Tags: flowchart, espocrm

what I'm trying to do, is to create a flowchart that check the status of the lead, if the assigned user changes the status to Not interested, then the assigned user will be changed to another one in the round robin, and after 1 month excluding weekends, if the status of the lead did not change, then the status will be updated to Junk.

My main issue is I don't want to use Timer to wait, because it might cause delays in the system, and because there are many other processes running also.

So, is there a way where I could make the flow wait 1 month excluding weekends before checking if status has changed by the second assigned user. Something maybe with datetime\month and formula.

I am trying to check for example the ModifiedAt after one month excluding Sundays and Saturdays.

Many Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Actually, I don't have a code. It is implemented on Espocrm flowchart. But, I was wondering if it was possible to do it using these formulas https://github.com/espocrm/documentation/blob/master/i18n/pl_PL/administration/formula.md